# reading first line of a file in c

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am very new to C and I am having trouble with the most fundamental ideas in C.  We are starting structures and basically the assignment we are working on is to read a delimited file and save the contents into a structure.  The first line of the file has the number of entries and alls that I am trying to do at the moment is get the program to read and save that number and print it out.  Please do not assume I know anything about C I really am very new to this.

This code is giving me a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct info{
  char name[100];
  char number[12];
  char address[100];
  char city[20];
  char state[2];
  int zip;
};

int strucCount;
char fileText[1];

int main(char *file)
{
  FILE *fileStream = fopen(file, "r");
  fgets(fileText, 1, fileStream);

  printf("\n%s\n",fileText);

  fclose(fileStream);

}
```

Here is the sample file

```
4
mike|203-376-5555|7 Melba Ave|Milford|CT|06461
jake|203-555-5555|8 Melba Ave|Hartford|CT|65484
snake|203-555-5555|9 Melba Ave|Stamford|CT|06465
liquid|203-777-5555|2 Melba Ave|Barftown|CT|32154
```

Thanks for everyones comments, they helped a lot, sorry to Jim.  I am working on very little sleep and didn't mean to offend anyone, I am sure we have all been there haha.

Comment: try something like this http://cfiddle.net/HPitJP

Comment: I meant I know what I have learned in class thus far, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi - Sidharth Mudgal answered your immediate question: you need to make your read buffer ("fileText") bigger; this should fix the segmentation violation. ALSO: the parameters to `main(int argc, char *argv[])` are wrong. Q: Could you post an example line from your text file?

Comment: @paulsm4 No, the OP's segmentation fault is in fgets, because of an attempt to open a non-existent file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUGGESTION:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define MAXLINE 80
    #define MAXRECORDS 10

    struct info{
      char name[100];
      char number[12];
      char address[100];
      char city[20];
      char state[2];
      int zip;
    };

    int 
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      FILE *fp = NULL;
      int nrecs = 0;
      char line[MAXLINE];
      struct info input_records[MAXRECORDS];

      /* Check for cmd arguments */
      if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("ERROR: you must specify file name!\n");
        return 1;

      /* Open file */
      fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      if (!fp) {
        perror ("File open error!\n");
        return 1;
      }

      /* Read file and parse text into your data records */
      while (!feof (fp)) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof (line), fp) {
          printf("next line= %s\n", line);
          parse(line, input_records[nrecs]);
          nrecs++;
        }
      }

      /* Done */
      fclose (fp);
      return 0;
    }    
  fclose(fileStream);

}
```

Key points:

- Note use of "argc/argv[]" to read input filename from command line
- line, nrecs, etc are all local variables (not globals)
- Check for error conditions like "filename not given" or "unable to open file"
- Read your data in a loop, until end of input file
- Parse the data you've read from the text file into an array of binary records (TBD)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, there is a lot going on in this that I cannot follow, it kills me I can write a complex java program but C is killing me.  What is the function of the int argc, all that I want to pass to the program is the file name, such as ./prog info.txt what function does the other parameter serve?

Comment: Ah I got it to read the first line, thank you for this suggestion even though I am not sure what it all means at the moment

Comment: Q: What is the function of `main (int argc, char *argv[])`?  Like Java, "main()" has a standard format.  You can't mess with it ;).  "argc" is the #/command line arguments (including program name); argv is the arguments themselves (just like "args[]" in Java, except "argc[0]" is the executable's name and path).  "argc" is equivalent to Java "args.length".

Comment: The struct input_record is that just making an array of size 10?

Comment: @Zach It's a typo ... it should be `struct info input_record[MAXRECORDS]`. `struct info` is a type, so it's just defining a variable called input_record that is an array of MAXRECORDS struct infos.

Comment: @Zach Ok, to be honest I have absolutely no interest in helping someone who wants other people to do his work for him. Goodbye.

Comment: @Zach Of course it's not what you meant, it's what you're *doing*. *Sheesh* indeed.

Comment: Well I thank you for your help thus far, sorry to be offensive.